# Highchart not showing 0 data correctly for pie chart

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts, pie-chart

I have a highchart(pie chart) with multiple fields (here added only two). Which is giving me issue for 0 values.

The conditions are as described below:

If my first field is 100% the pie chart renders a line of 0% for the other field

Refer to this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rndmmuz6/4/

```
data: [{
        name: 'Check1',
        y: 100
    },
    {
        name: 'Check2',
        y: 0
    }]
```

but if my second field is 100% then the pie chart does not render a 0% field for the first fields

Refer to this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rndmmuz6/3/

```
 data: [{
        name: 'Check1',
        y: 0
    },
    {
        name: 'Check2',
        y: 100
    }]
```

I want the line to always appear.

Comment: you can use `y: 0.01` till the problem is sorted out. If y is zero there should be no render   technically in any case.

Answer (score 2):

This bug have been reported [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4246), you can use `borderWith : 0` like that :

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
            style: {
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
            }
        },
        borderWidth:0
    }
},
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rndmmuz6/5/)

Comment: border 0 removes the border from appearing but I want the border to always appear. tried with borderwidth 1. Thought it would fix it. Did not work though.

Answer (score 0):

Destroying the graphical element of the point can be a workaround here:

```
    events: {
      load: function() {
        this.series[0].points.forEach(function(p) {
          if(!p.y) {
            p.graphic.destroy();
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/ojd4wn3f/

Answer (score 0):

I found the following code which overrides the shapeArgs of the highchart to render the line

Refer to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rndmmuz6/7/

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.seriesTypes.pie.prototype, 'drawPoints', function (proceed) {
    Highcharts.each(this.points, function (p) {
        if (p.shapeArgs) {
            p.shapeArgs.open = false;
        }
    });
    proceed.call(this);
});
```